# Flutter material drawer navigate to pages

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I'm still learning.

I have created a plutter project with a material driven sidebar by following the tutorial of [Techie Blossom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SjvhAUR9aw&list=PLaEr1_k6bCzH9IdtZT6uuKQlu5QVuHW37&index=26&t=1858s)

Techie however did not explain how to add navigation to different pages in his tutorial.
I have been wrecking my brain trying to figure out how to do it but no luck yet.

Can you guys please help me. I have added my project to GitHub where you guys can [find the code](https://github.com/JaserJsk/flutter_playground/tree/master/gambit_app).

Thank you

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: drawerBackgroundColor,
        title: Text('MD Drawer'),
      ),
      body: BlocProvider<CmdNavBloc>(
        create: (context) => CmdNavBloc(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<CmdNavBloc, NavigationStates>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is Dashboard) {
                  return DashBoardPage();
                } else if (state is Search) {
                  return SearchPage();
                } else if (state is Notifications) {
                  return SearchPage();
                } else if (state is Errors) {
                  return SearchPage();
                } else if (state is Settings) {
                  return SearchPage();
                }
              },
            ),
            CmdDrawer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How should I help? Forking your repo and adding the navigation? or just giving a plane answer with an example here?

Comment: What ever is easier for you, I have been at this for hours now and i'm not getting closer to the solution. If forking the repo is ok for you then I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you are looking for, but I saw that you were trying to use a Bloc to achieve that. It's a good option, so what you can do is use it, in the MyHomePage class as you can see below:

```
BlocProvider<CmdNavBloc>(
    create: (context) => CmdNavBloc(),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        BlocBuilder<CmdNavBloc, NavigationStates>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is Dashboard) {
              return DashBoardPage();
            } else {
              if (state is Search) {
                return SearchPage();
              } else {
                ....
              }
            }
          },
        ),
        CmdDrawer(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Remember that Bloc works with Events and States, so you can add a state for each page as follows in your CmdNavBloc class and also yield this states instead of a Widget:

```
abstract class NavigationStates {}

class Dashboard extends NavigationStates {}

class Search extends NavigationStates {}

...

class CmdNavBloc extends Bloc<NavigationEvents, NavigationStates> {
  @override
  NavigationStates get initialState => Dashboard();

  @override
  Stream<NavigationStates> mapEventToState(NavigationEvents event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case NavigationEvents.DashboardClickedEvent:
        yield Dashboard();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.SearchClickedEvent:
        yield Search();
        break;

      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Next, you have a list of each item to populate in your Menu Drawer, you can add a Event to each item to  make the things easy in the navigation, there are a lot of options to achieve this too, but is the easiest by the moment:

```
class CmdNavModel {
  String title;
  IconData icon;
  NavigationEvents navigationEvent;

  CmdNavModel({this.title, this.icon, this.navigationEvent});
}

List<CmdNavModel> navigationItems = [
  CmdNavModel(
      title: 'Dashboard',
      icon: Icons.insert_chart,
      navigationEvent: NavigationEvents.DashboardClickedEvent),
  CmdNavModel(
      title: 'Search',
      icon: Icons.search,
      navigationEvent: NavigationEvents.SearchClickedEvent),
  CmdNavModel(
      title: 'Notifications',
      icon: Icons.error,
      navigationEvent: NavigationEvents.NotificationsClickedEvent),
  CmdNavModel(
      title: 'Errors',
      icon: Icons.notifications,
      navigationEvent: NavigationEvents.ErrorsClickedEvent),
  CmdNavModel(
      title: 'Settings',
      icon: Icons.settings,
      navigationEvent: NavigationEvents.SettingsClickedEvent),
];
```

And finally, you can use the Bloc in the CmdDrawer as follows, and add the events to the Bloc from the onTap in your item: `

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CmdNavBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<CmdNavBloc>(context);

    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        builder: (context, widget) => getWidget(bloc,context, widget),
    );
}

...


Widget getWidget(CmdNavBloc bloc,context, widget) {
    ...
    itemBuilder: (context, counter) {
        return CollapsingListTile(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                bloc.add(navigationItems[counter].navigationEvent);
                currentSelectedIndex = counter;
              });
            },
            isSelected: currentSelectedIndex == counter,
            title: navigationItems[counter].title,
            icon: navigationItems[counter].icon,
            animationController: _animationController,
          );
        },

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I'm getting an error on - `return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, widget) => getWidget(bloc, context, widget),
    );` --- Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 3 found.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to put that part of the code, you have to receive the parameter in the getWidget method:   Widget getWidget(CmdNavBloc bloc,context, widget) {}, I am going to update the answer too.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now in main - `builder: (context, state) {...` --->

This function has a return type of 'StatelessWidget', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Comment: I will post my current `Main.dart` file

Comment: Please look at my main class

Comment: That is right, you can add a Default Widget in that part, for example at the end of your else if structure you can add a DashBoardPage:  `else if (state is Settings) { 
                  return SearchPage();
                } else return DashBoardPage();`

Comment: Well something is still wrong - I did as you said but it is not navigating to any other page then Dashboard page. 

I have updated the code in Github - please take alook

Comment: I saw the problem, in the Bloc you forgot to update the `yield` in the states, first update the: `NavigationStates get initialState => Dashboard();` and next all the `yield parts`, instead of `DashboardPage()` you have to put just `Dashboard()` . To avoid confusions in the future you can use DashboardState as a name, same in the next pages. Hope it help you.